# EF Core - Specify characters that has to be within string for saving to succeed

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core, ef-fluent-api

Working on one of my own spare time project, using Entity Framework Core to persist data, i would like to configure, via Fluent Api, that a property of type string, must contain a selection of character for it to be valid when saving.

Given a User as so...

```cs
public class User : IUser
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public byte[] Version { get; set; }
        public string Username { get; set; }
        public string Password { get; set; }
        public string Email { get; set; }

        ...
    }
```

And configuring with Fluent Api like this...

```cs
public class UserConfig : EntityConfig<User>
    {
        public override void Configure(EntityTypeBuilder<User> builder)
        {
            base.Configure(builder);

            ...

            builder.HasIndex(x => x.Username).IsUnique();
            builder.Property(x => x.Username).HasMaxLength(30);
        }
    }
```

How would i create an Extension method for PropertyBuilder of type string, that Entity Framework Core can understand? So that i could do something along these lines...

```cs
builder.Property(x => x.Email).MustContain('@', '.');
```

The Extension method would look something like the code below, it is the logic within it, that i am unsure of how to construct.

```cs
public static class PropertyBuilderExtensions
    {
        public static PropertyBuilder<string> MustContain(this PropertyBuilder<string> builder, params char[] chars)
        {
            // ???
        }
    }
```

It would allow the possibility to validate that for example an Email contains the required @ and . characters, which is always within a valid Email, when trying to save it to the database.
This check could also be done manually when creating a user, but i still fell like it would be a good thing, if the database simply denied saving it, if it didn't contain the specified characters.

Fell free to ask questions if there is need for any further explanation.

Comment: You can attach a validator to the property. Also, if this really is only about validating an email, then there's already a built-in [`EmailAddressAttribute`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.componentmodel.dataannotations.emailaddressattribute?view=netframework-4.8) validator you can use.

Comment: @TanveerBadar How would one apply this validator, preferably via Fluent Api? I'm not a big fan of Attributes, if it can be done otherwise.